# How to search and filter for nested property using Lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an object shaped like this:

```
const config = [
  {
    id: 'foo',
    props,
  },
  {
    id: 'bar',
    props,
    children: [
      {
        id: 'bat',
        props,
      },
      {
        id: 'baz',
        props,
        children: [
          {
            // this is the object I want to access
            id: 'qux',
            props,
          },
        ]
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

I need to access the object where the `id` property is `qux` by using some sort of "`.deep`" (recursive?) filter on the `config` array. Or some kind of "`.flatten`", then "`.filter`" combo pattern.

How can I do this using Lodash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with plain js with recursion and some method that will loop the array and exit on first match like `some`.

```js
const config = [{"id":"foo","props":1},{"id":"bar","props":1,"children":[{"id":"bat","props":1},{"id":"baz","props":1,"children":[{"id":"qux","props":"target prop",}]}]}]

function find(data, id) {
  let result = null;

  data.some(e => {
    if (e.id == id) return result = e;
    if (!result && e.children) result = find(e.children, id)
  })

  return result;
}

const result = find(config, 'qux')
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a vanilla ES6 solution without lodash or any other package. Simply flatten your original structure (I used a simple recursive function that takes advantage of [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) - but there are other ways to flatten) then use [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get your desired element.

For example (I nested the array deeper with some phony data, just to show that the solution should work no matter how many levels deep the `children` continue on for:

```js
const props = 'Default props data..';
const config = [{
  id: 'foo',
  props,
}, {
  id: 'bar',
  props,
  children: [{
    id: 'bat',
    props,
  }, {
    id: 'baz',
    props,
    children: [{
      id: 'qux',
      props: 'This is qux props',
      children: [{
        id: 'abc',
        props: 'This is abc props',
        children: [{
          id: 'bcd',
          props: 'This is bcd props'
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }]
}];

//A function to create a nice, single level structure 
const flatten = arr => {
  return arr.reduce((accum, el) => {
    accum.push({
      id: el.id,
      props: el.props
    });
    if (el.children) {
      accum = accum.concat(flatten(el.children));
    }
    return accum;
  }, []);
};

//A function to find our desired element by ID within a flattened array
const getElById = (arr, id) => flatten(arr).find(el => el.id === id);

console.log(getElById(config, 'qux'))
console.log(getElById(config, 'abc'))
console.log(getElById(config, 'bcd'))
```

Comment: +1. I really appreciated this answer too. I wish we could accept two answers so I could have accepted yours too.

Comment: No worries - glad it was useful!